# Delphi Application Hangs

Tags: windows, delphi, dwm

I have a working application that needs to clear and setup very large buffers from time to time. Sometimes the operation takes longer than 5 seconds to complete and then Desktop Window Manager times out and declares the application to be hung.

Is there any technique to cause DWM to allow more time before this happens?

Delphi Seattle, Windows 10, 64-bit application

Comment: Clear and set-up the buffer in a separate thread. Have the thread call a callback when it's done.

Comment: Heavy work, especially big loops, should never be done in the application's main thread. This should be the responsibility of a worker thread.

Comment: Apart from the obvious of putting slow code in a thread, you may clearing your buffers very inefficiently. Naturally with all the detail you've provided about how you clear said buffers it's a trivial matter to solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

The right solution is to put the long running task in a thread so that it does not block your UI thread. You should do that.

If you cannot bring yourself to take that task one, and it can be quite tricky, you can always disable ghosting by calling [`DisableProcessWindowsGhosting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415.aspx). But you really ought not to do that. You really ought to put the work in a thread.